# What does a 204 response mean when calling the MOVE for an azure resource (as opposed to 202)

Tags: azure, http-response-codes

When calling Azure with a request to MOVE a resource, the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/move-resources#response) say that the response can be:

- 202 Accepted
- 204 No Content
- Other Status Codes (CloudError)

I get the error codes, but what is the difference between 202 and 204 in this context?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your query?

Comment: Sure - when would I get 202 vs. 204? what would either mean regarding my request?

Comment: Have you tried any code and got these as responses?

Comment: I got 202, didn't get 204 and that's why I'm asking

Comment: Can you share the code here?

Comment: No sorry, but basically just a REST call to a resource following the docs that I linked to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***202 Accepted:***

Generally, `202 response` often indicates that the request has been accepted and will be processed asynchronously.

In API's, 202 Accepted response means that the request was accepted and is being processed. So here, it means that the operation for moving a resource from one to another is still in progress.

***204 No content:***

In general, `204 No Content` response means that the server has successfully processed the request, but there is no content to return in the response.

Here `204 No Content` indicates that the request was accepted and successfully processed, but there is no response body. It means the moving operation has been successfully completed.

I tried to get the resource groups using postman to see if the response was working properly, and it worked as follows.

[image]

Refer [doc1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204) & [doc2](https://restfulapi.net/http-status-202-accepted/) by @Lokesh Gupta for more detailed information.

Comment: so you suggest that it depends whether the move completed or not?

Comment: As per the current API call, yes it is. @orirab